# jquery conversion for this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
for (i=1; i<=len; i++) {
        var optcheck = col+'|'+document.getElementById('color').options[i].value;
        text = document.getElementById('color').options[i].text.split(' - ');
}
```

This is part of the original code from javascript. I have successfully converted much of the other stuff into jquery but I can't seem to figure out how to convert this into jquery.

Please note that col is just value I am passing when calling the function which is usually "16"

Here is what I got so far:

```
    for (i=1; i<=len; i++) {
        var optcheck = col+'|'+$('#color').val(i);
        text = $('#color').val(i).text.split(' - ');
      }
```

Also, the original code works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari but in IE (all version from 6 to 9) I get an error saying 'options[...].value' is not null or not an object

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since you removed `options` in the 2nd snippet - i vote that you're looking at a wrong part of code. Also `$('#color').val(i).text` - this is just wrong.

Comment: I think the header of the for loop should be `(i=0; i<len; i++)`. That may resolve the issue with IE.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: You are correct. That was causing the issue. I am implementing your suggested method for the loop right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mis-calling `val`.

Change it to `$('#color option').eq(i).text()` and `$('#color option').eq(i).val()`

Comment: Any reason to add `option` selector?

Comment: @zerk: Otherwise, it would get the `i`'th `#color` element, which is not what he wants.

Comment: @SLaks: oops, missed it with `option#color`

Comment: @SLaks The OP really shouldn't query for `$('#color option')` twice and inside a loop...

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks!!!! Seems to work. Do you know why I get the stupid IE errors for value is null or not an object?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: How do you propose I do this without calling it twice inside a loop?

Comment: @Eddy Is `len` larger than the `length` of `options`? That may be the reason why IE complains...

Comment: @Eddy You just query for `$('#color option')` once and then run `each()` on that result. See my answer.

Comment: @Eddy: You can (and should) store `$('#color option')` in a variable.

Comment: @SLaks: Store `$('#color option') in a variable?  Sorry I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#color option').each(function() {
    var a = col + '|' + this.value,
        b = this.text.split(' - ');

    // do stuff with a and b
});
```